# CKEditor Not Appropriately Displaying Tags

Tags: javascript, html, express, ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEDITOR for my express app, but I'm running into an issue where I try to use the list element tags, but instead of displaying my content with the appropriate HTML format, I am shown the tags. I recently configured the editor to remove the `<p>` tags from appearing, but it appears that there is something else I need to add to get tags appearing in the correct HTML format.

**UPDATE:** Attached is a screenshot of what the source code looks like for those `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

[image: Ul elements]

[image: Use of the list element]

[image: How it appears]

blogpost-create.ejs:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <% include ../partials/head %>
        <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.5/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <% include ../partials/header %>
        </header>

        <div class="grid grid-pad">
            <div class="col-1-1">
                <h1>Blog Create</h1>


                <form action="/admin/posts/create" method="POST">
                    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
                    Author: 
                        <select name="author">
                            <option value="Author">Author</option>
                        </select><br>
                    Category: 
                        <select name="category">
                            <option value="Analytics/SEO/SEM">Analytics/SEO/SEM</option>
                            <option value="Advice">Advice</option>
                            <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                            <option value="Thoughts">Thoughts</option>
                        </select><br>
                    Tagline: <input type="text" maxlength="160" name="tagline"><br>
                    Content:<br>
                    <textarea name="content" id="blog-editor" rows="10" cols="80">

                    </textarea><br>
                    Tags: <input type="text" name="tags"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

            <script>
        // Replace the <textarea id="blog-editor"> with a CKEditor
                    // instance, using default configuration.

                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'blog-editor' );
                    CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = 2;


        </script>


    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

routes.js:

```
   var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
    var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
    var paginate = require('express-paginate');

    //index 
    router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));




        router.route('/') 


            // START GET method
            .get(function(req, res, next) {

                Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {




                    if (err) return next(err)

                            if (err)
                                res.send(err);


                            function dateDisplayed(timestamp) {
                                var date = new Date(timestamp || Date.now() );
                                return (date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear());
                            }


                            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // get the blog title
                            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // get the author name
                            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // get tagline
                            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // get the blog content
                            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // get the category
                            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // get the tags
                            blogpost.date = dateDisplayed(req.body.date);

                            console.log(blogpost.date);

                            res.format({
                                html: function() {
                                    res.render('pages/index', {
                                        blogpost: blogpost,
                                        pageCount: pageCount,
                                        itemCount: itemCount
                                    })
                                },
                                json: function() {

                                    res.json({
                                        object: 'blogpost',
                                        has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                        data: blogpost
                                    })
                                }
                            }); // END res.format(html, json)
                }); // END Blogpost.paginate
            }); // END GET method

    router.route('/admin/posts/create')

        // START POST method
            .post(function(req, res) {

                console.log("New instance");

                var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

                blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
                blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
                blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
                blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
                blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
                blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
                blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
                    //Save Blog Post
                    blogpost.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);

                        res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                    });

            }) // END POST method


            .get(function(req, res) {
                res.render('pages/blogpost-create');
            });

    function getSearchCriteria(params) {
          return {
              blogUrl: params.blogpost_blogUrl
          };
    }



    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_blogUrl')

        .get(function (req, res) {
             var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
             Blogpost.findOne(searchCriteria, function (err, blogpost) {
                 if (err)
                     res.send(err);
                 res.render('pages/blogpost', {
                     blogpost: blogpost
                 })
             })
         })
         .put(function (req, res) {
             var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
             var updated = getBlogpostUpdate(req.body)
             Blogpost.findOneAndUpdate(searchCriteria, updated, function (err, updated) {
                 if (err)
                     res.send(err);


                 res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
             });
         })
         .delete(function (req, res) {
             var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
             Blogpost.findOneAndRemove(searchCriteria, function (err, removed) {
                 if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                 res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
             });
         });

    module.exports = router;
```

blogpost.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="blog-content">
                <h1><%= blogpost.title %></h1>
                <p><%= blogpost.content %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't show the code displaying the data got from the CKEditor and the problem is there or on the way from the editor to the place where you display the content. Please update your question.

Comment: Hey @Reinmar I added the additional code. blogpost.ejs is where the content is displayed and also added is the routes.ejs